# Cancel/Abort an async function

Tags: node.js, express, asynchronous, async-await, socket.io

There is an express server on Node js
The client can create a task in which some processes are executed (cycles, communication with the database, etc.)
Communication between the client and the server is built through socket.io
How can I implement canceling/killing this function?
The client must be able to manually terminate a function early

I tried to do it through child_process, everything works as it should, but a separate process is created that consumes RAM (50MB) with the necessary libraries, and there can be 50, 100, 300 tasks

Client start task

```
socket.on('tasks:launch', (collect) => {
 (async () => {
   await collector_obj.tasks.task(uid, data, io);
 })();
});
```

Client stop task

```
socket.on('tasks:stop', (collect) => {
   // kill func
});
```

Test func:

```
task: async (uid, data, io) => {
    const sleep = (ms) => new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, ms));
    while(1) {
        await sleep(1000);
        console.log(Date.now());
    }
}
```

Comment: What is collector_obj.tasks? This would require to keep a pool of tasks in order to be able to abort them at least

Comment: This is a separate file with various functions ( export default{ auth, task, etc } that are imported into the main file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to add cancelling mechanism to `async..await` but this requires to explicitly support this at any point, `AbortController` is a conventional way to handle this.

It's necessary to keep a list of tasks to be able to interact with them, e.g. task pool. For a case that requires only aborting all is needed, it could be:

```
const tasks = {
  controllers: new Set(),
  add() {
    const controller = new AbortController();
    this.controllers.add(controller);
    const abortPromise = new Promise((r, reject) => {
      controller.signal.onabort = () => reject(new DOMException('', 'AbortError'));
    });

    try {
      while(1) {
        await Promise.race([sleep(1000), abortPromise]);
        await Promise.race([sleep(2000), abortPromise]);
      }
    } finally {
      this.controllers.delete(controller);
    }
  },
  removeAll() {
    for (const controller of this.controllers)
      controller.abort();
      this.controllers.clear();
  }
```

Wher `tasks.removeAll` can be called on `tasks:stop`. Can be optimized further if `sleep()` is cancelable by nature and can be provided with current controller instance.

ES promise implementation doesn't specifically support cancelation, and `async..await` syntax forces the use of native promises. The use of some implementation of cancelable promises like `p-cancelable` requires to not use syntactic sugar. In this case a list of cancelable promises could be stored instead of controllers.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll try this, but what if I create worker_threads (Worker), what will be better?

Comment: Depends on a task, it won't if it isn't intensive enough to justify the overhead of a worker